# mux-player-react don't recognize object-fit cover

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mux-video

I'm using mux-player-react on a next.js site to implement a large background looped movie.

https://website-agobay-coming-soon-5iemrgd6o-hhag.vercel.app/

The video should be object-fit: cover to cover all the browser window. unfortunately it doesn't work.

eather with:

```
 .videoMob {
 --controls: none;
 --media-object-fit: cover;
 --media-object-position: center;
```

or:

```
 .videoMob {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
 min-width: 100vw;
 min-height: 100vh;
 overflow: hidden;
 object-fit: cover;
```

It's strange, if I use the mux-video-react class, it works fine but the video has a jumpcut and it don't show the video on mobile devices.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`object-fit` seems to be working but the video doesn't take up all the vertical space of its parent element. If you can use `height: 100vh` on the video tag, it should work.

On another note - for a background video like this, native HTML5 video does the job as well ...

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `videoMob` class styles to look like this, it should solve your issue:

```css
.videoMob {
 position: absolute;
 inset: 0;
 min-width: 100vw;
 min-height: 100vh;
 overflow: hidden;
 object-fit: cover;
}
```

Let me know if you have any other questions around using `mux-player`!